# Is there any word or phrases that can replace greed and greedy?

Tags: creative-writing, poetry

Apparently, greed and greedy are weak words in poetry, so you can't use them, but what other words would you use?

> The pirate greed for their gold.

> And the adventurers are greedy

> In their quests for adventures

> Until an arrow in the knee they take.

I can't think of a way to reword this. It's like impossible, and I just think it's ridiculous to think of these two words as weak.

Comment: "Apparently, greed and greedy are weak words in poetry, so you can't use them." I agree with you that this is ridiculous. However, using both 'greed' and 'greedy' within two lines doesn't sound so good to me (unless it was part of a deliberate repetition). If you want to change one or both of them, or any other words, and you don't know what to change them to, follow Anna A. Fitzgerald's advice :)

Answer (score 2):

Many.

Consider consulting a thesaurus:

https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/greed

https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/greedy

Answer (score 1):

The English in this example is not idiomatic, and "greed" cannot be used as a verb, as appears attempted here. Also, we generally avoid repetition (greed/greedy; adventurers/adventure) unless it serves a purpose. Maybe better:
Pirates lust after gold, and
Adventurers are greedy in their quest for excitement ...
Or: Adventurers grasp at the thrill of their quest

Comment: I think it might be 'pirate greed' as a noun? But I'm not sure

Comment: Maybe, but as the second line is a sentence with subject and predicate, one can misread the first line as being parallel to the second--as a full sentence instead of a fragment. There is nothing wrong with fragments per se, if they are effectively used..

Comment: English verbs nouns regularly.  However, in that case it should either be "The pirate**s** greed for their gold", or "The pirate greed**s** for their gold".  (Of course, with a preceding line to add context, the noun-form as suggested by @DM_with_secrets can also work)

Comment: @Chronocidal Wish I could give more than one upvote for your first sentence!